# How to parse AMF data in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, client, amf

So I see that there are a few [Rails plugins for](http://blog.rubyamf.org/) [serving AMF](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-rails/overview.html). However, is there a library that I can use in a Ruby environment to act as an AMF client: to read AMF data, and deserialize it into a Ruby object?

If not, how could I best go about using [tools built in other languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format#Support_for_AMF)? I suppose I could write something in Python or Java or whatever, and call it from Ruby directly via backticks... but I'd first like to ensure that there isn't really any better option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rocket-amf](http://github.com/warhammerkid/rocket-amf) is what you're looking for. It support serialization and deserialization of AMF0 and AMF3 data directly into native ruby objects.